# Documenting a ggplot2 Statistic extension - devtools::document() is not creating packagename-ggproto.Rd

Tags: r, ggplot2, devtools, r-package, roxygen2

I'm creating a package which will contain a new ggplot2 Statistic.

I'm using the `ggplot2::ggproto` to create the new Statistic, but I'm having problems with the documentation with roxygen2. After running `devtools::document()`, I got:

> mypackagename-ggproto.Rd is missing name/title. Skipping

I tried to follow other packages' examples (such as [here](https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance/blob/master/R/stat-counth.R), [here](https://github.com/cran/ggalt/blob/master/R/stat-stepribbon.r), and [here](https://github.com/cran/gginnards/blob/master/R/stat-debug-group.R)) but I got the same problem. As a minimal reproducible example, I provide the following content of my stat-test.R file:

```
#' @title My Statistic
#'
#' @description blah blah
#'
#' @param ... other arguments.
#' @param na.rm a logical value indicating ...
#'
#' @export
#' 
stat_test <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "segment", 
                     position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, 
                     linetype="dotted", show.legend = NA, 
                     inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  ggplot2::layer(
    stat = StatTEST, 
    data = data, 
    mapping = mapping, 
    geom = geom, 
    position = position, 
    show.legend = show.legend, 
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, linetype = linetype, ...)
  )
}

#' @rdname mypackagename-ggproto
#' @format NULL
#' @usage NULL
#' @export
StatTEST <- ggplot2::ggproto("StatTEST", ggplot2::Stat,
                       compute_group = function(data, scales, ...) {
                         ## Compute the line segment endpoints

                         data[nrow(data), c("from", "to")] <- 
                           c(
                             data[1, "from"], data[1, "to"]
                             )

                         x = data[data$from, 1]
                         y = data[data$from, 2]
                         xend = data[data$to, 1]
                         yend = data[data$to, 2]

                         data.frame(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)

                       },
                       required_aes = c("x", "y", "from", "to")
 )
```

I read the roxygen2 [Generating Rd Files](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html) vignette as well, but I couldn't find a solution. I can't figure out why `#' @rdname mypackagename-ggproto` is not producing my `mypackagename-ggproto.Rd` file.

I would appreciate any help.

Seesion Info:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.0

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  
LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] emstreeR_1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18         pillar_1.3.0         compiler_3.5.1       
plyr_1.8.4           bindr_0.1.1          tools_3.5.1          
digest_0.6.15       
 [8] memoise_1.1.0        tibble_1.4.2         gtable_0.2.0         
pkgconfig_2.0.1      rlang_0.2.1          rstudioapi_0.7       
commonmark_1.5      
[15] yaml_2.2.0           bindrcpp_0.2.2       withr_2.1.2          
dplyr_0.7.6          stringr_1.3.1        roxygen2_6.1.0       xml2_1.2.0          
[22] desc_1.2.0           devtools_1.13.6      rprojroot_1.3-2      
grid_3.5.1           tidyselect_0.2.4     scatterplot3d_0.3-41 glue_1.3.0          
[29] R6_2.2.2             ggplot2_3.0.0        purrr_0.2.5          
magrittr_1.5         backports_1.1.2      scales_0.5.0         
assertthat_0.2.0    
[36] colorspace_1.3-2     stringi_1.2.4        lazyeval_0.2.1       
munsell_0.5.0        crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Have you tried making a dummy documentation file by documenting `NULL` and setting an informative `@name`. Then using `@rdname` to refer to that?

Comment: I've tried using `@name` instead of `@title`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but in the `Generating Rd files` vignette it seems you can only use `@rdname` to associate a function's documentation with a doc file that already exists, not to create a new one. They use it in 2 ways: 1) `@rdname add` to document with the normally documented function `add` and 2) `@rdname arith` which documents it in a dummy doc file consisting of `NULL` (and no function) created with the `@name arith`. Search for `@rdname arith` to see the example

Comment: @divibisan Ok, I see what you mean, but have you saw the examples from existing packages? It seems they use the first way. I will try the second one and see what I get.

Comment: @divisiban I guess it works when I follow you suggestion. I have not noticed that the other packages' examples were also creating new geoms. And they were first documenting ggroto-objects in those geom .R files which is not my case. I'm only creating new Stats. So I documented NULL after `stat_test()` and set an informative name `mypackagename-ggproto` as you said. After this I documented the StatTEST object. Please, post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it. I will also edit it adding the complete code for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@rdname` tag associates a function's documentation with a doc file that already exists, but cannot be used to create a new one. If you look at the [Generating Rd Files Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html) you'll see that they always use `@rdname` to link a function's documentation to an existing file:

In the below example, the `add` function is documented normally. By using `@rdname add`, the `times` function will be documented in the same file as `add`

```
#' Basic arithmetic
#'
#' @param x,y numeric vectors.
add <- function(x, y) x + y

#' @rdname add
times <- function(x, y) x * y
```

If you don't want to build a documentation file around a single function, you still need to create the file before using `@rdname` to associate functions with it. You can do this by creating and documenting a dummy function using the `@name` tag. Then you can use `@rdname` to document functions in that same dummy file:

```
#' Basic arithmetic
#'
#' @param x,y numeric vectors.
#' @name arith
NULL

#' @rdname arith
add <- function(x, y) x + y

#' @rdname arith
times <- function(x, y) x * y
```